# Login to Facebook from Android app without inserting manually credentials

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I'm wiriting an Android app that will be used by bar's clients to take a selfie of themselves and then automatically post it on the bar's Facebook page. What I need is a way to automatic login with the bar's Facebook account without entering username and password inside the login dialog, but providing them by source code (it will be hardcoded, the app will be installed only in the tablet of the bar).

Thank you

Marco

Answer (score 0):

You should use Facebook SDK in your app.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/

for facebook login:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/v2.0

Comment: Thank you, but I've already seen these pages. What I really want is to DON'T show the authentication dialog and to pass by myself hardcoded username and password.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do this as well and have yet to find an Android-only solution. However, I did get it to work by posting to facebook through PHP that is hosted on my server. Once I got the PHP to work, all I had to do was use HttpClient on Android to post the image to the PHP page.

I know this is a bit of a workaround, but I was in almost the exact same situation as you and it works perfectly now.

If you have a webserver to put up PHP code, follow this tutorial
http://www.pontikis.net/blog/auto_post_on_facebook_with_php 
to get the PHP code to post to your facebook wall.

I hope this helps, if I find an Android-only solution, I will update my answer.